# Make a radial gradient in edge

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am trying to make a radical gradient in edge but it doesn't work :
`background-image: radical-gradient(#3A3456, #211E2E);`
Do you know why and can you give a solution to my problem pls?
Thanks

I also tried to use a conic gradient to make a radical gradient but it was more difficult to do it and I didn't  get the result I wanted.

I am expecting something like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbVnO.png)

Comment: So radical dude :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you want:
`background-image: radial-gradient(#3A3456, #211E2E));`

The issue was a typing problem. It is not a radical-gradient, but instead a *radial*-gradient